# redirect url in safari extension

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, redirect

In safari extension demo page,I fount [Blocker Safari Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/samplecode/BlockerSafariExtension/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010127),which can block element matching specific pattern,but I have one question: Is it possible to redirect a url like chrome webRequest.

I have found [this link](http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-1298/dom/BeforeLoadEvent.idl), which says url property is readonly, and I have tried rewrite `event.url`, it didn't work at all.

Does anyone know how to redirect url in safari extension ??

Answer (score 0):

you can always redirect a tab object by saying tab.url="www.stackoverflow.com";

Tab is a SafariBrowserTab object.

Comment: I want to redirect some css,js based on some pattern, so I don't think Tab object wok for me.

Comment: What you can do is have a content script (injected script) for all html pages and in your content script you can check if your "some css/js" files are loaded in the DOM. If they are then you can send a message to your global context using the messaging API. From the message event you can get the event.target and redirect it to the URL of your choice.